# Amazon EC2 Ubuntu Instance Maximum File Upload Size

Tags: php, ubuntu, file-upload, amazon-ec2, upload-max-filesize

I was given an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu Instance. We are task to create a web application that includes uploading a client video. I have created a file upload application in my localhost and it is working fine. When I migrated the code to the virtual host server, I cannot upload any video and even any file that exceeds `2Mb`. I tried editing the `php.ini` setting `upload_max_filesize` to `50M` and post_max_size to `1000M`.

After restarting Apache so many times, the update is not reflected in my `phpinfo()` information but changes were saved in my `php.ini` file.

[image]
[image]

I was suspecting that the Amazon EC2 instance given to me has a file upload restrictions but Im not sure if Im right. If I was wrong, how can I override the configuration below? Any help would be very much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I even made sure that I was editing the correct configuration file. Below are the screen shots:

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I tried following what is said in the [link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=410421#) with no luck. I have a lot of questions in mind about the link like:

1. What does *tomcatchesides* mean about `S3 bucket`? I uploaded the config file in `/var/www/html/.ebextensions` . Am I doing the right thing?

My `zzz.ini` contains the code below and I place it in `/etc/php.d/zzz.ini`:

```
[php]
post_max_size = 1000M
upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

My `myconfigfile.config` was located in `/var/www/html/.ebextensions/myconfigfile.config` and contains the code below:

```
files:
  "/etc/php.ini":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    source: http://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/php.ini

  "/etc/php.d/zzz.ini":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    source: http://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/zzz.ini
```

How to know the bucket name of my instance?

I also copied my `php.ini` from `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` to `/etc/php.ini` and restarted apache. Still no changes. Am I doing the right thing?

UPDATE:

I ask for the bucket name to the person who gave me the EC2 instance and her reply was.

> Yes, you were given access to an EC2 instance. S3 is a different
>   service provided by Amazon and that's not automatically available to
>   EC2 instances. We can create a bucket in S3 for you but it may no
>   longer be needed.
>
> The EC2 instance has around 8GB storage space. You should be able to
>   store multiple videos greater than 2MB in the EC2 file system and
>   access them directly.
>
> Using S3 for file uploads is a good idea especially when your software
>   goes to production. However, to simplify the setup, please use the
>   file system instead to store the videos.

UPDATE :

Running the following commands:

```
php -i | grep -i max_size
```

yields: ***post_max_size => 1000M => 1000M***

```
grep -ir "max_size" /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/
```

yieds nothing.

```
grep -ir "max_size" /etc/php/7.0/
```

yields

```
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini:post_max_size = 1000M
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini:post_max_size = 1000M
/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini:post_max_size = 1000M
```

My `phpinfo()` can be access through this [link](http://18.236.72.77/info.php)

Comment: Are you sure you updated the correct php.ini? The one to update should be mentioned near the top of that `phpinfo()` page.

Comment: @apokryfos --> Yes it was the same configuration file. I'll post a screenshot.

Comment: Also try `service php7-frm restart` (or php5-fpm or whatever the correct version is) if you're running FPM

Comment: @apokryfos --> I dont know about FPm and im not using it also.

Comment: @apokryfos, did you mean fpm?

Comment: @IgrewupwithSlackware i got it right 2 out of 3 times that has to count for something

Comment: Worse case you can just do `ini_set("post_max_size", "1000M")` in your code if these still don't work

Comment: @apokryfos --> I tried ini_set but still doesnt works. What shall I do?

Comment: ebextension are for Elastic bean stalk and not EC2, can you confirm if you are using plain EC2 instance or EBS?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I was using EC2 instance.

Comment: what is the output of `php -i | grep -i max_size`. Please add that to your question

Comment: @TarunLalwani post_max_size => 1000M => 1000M but my phpinfo() says 8M only.

Comment: Can you show the complete `phpinfo` page?

Comment: http://18.236.72.77/info.php CAn you access it?

Comment: Yes, I can. Can you run `grep -ir "max_size" /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/` and share the output in the question? Don't comment the output. I think your issue is that another conf is updating the max_size again

Comment: @TarunLalwani it has no output.

Comment: Please join this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171857/discussion-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-instance-maximum-file-upload-size) room

Comment: @TarunLalwani --> I couldn't log in to the chat room. I update my post above.

Comment: The only other possible thing that may happen is apache config is overriding this. Can you provide config for apache also? They also will have `conf.d` which will have additional config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys, for bothering all of you, my bad. I was banging my head for this for almost 4 days and it turns out that I have only made a syntax error in my php.ini. I updated my server php.ini with my newly installed php in my localhost and phpinfo() was updated after apache restart.

Answer (score 8):

After changin the php.ini file I also had to restart FPM:

`sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service`

before restarting apache:

`sudo systemctl restart httpd`

Comment: for an AWS EC2 hosted wordpress site I was troubleshooting, this was exactly the issue. had to restart php service in addition to httpd. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Check also for:

`/etc/php.ini`
or

`/etc/php-[version].ini`

and modify the value also in this file. If this is not sufficient, search for:

```
/etc/php.d/aws.ini
```

infact it is possible that AWS is overriding your value. If this is the case, the solution is to create a file named /etc/php.d/99uploadsize.ini containing only:

```
[php]
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

The name 99uploadsize.ini is not mandatory, but remember that the name should be in alphabetical order after aws.ini and in the same directory, because this is the order these ini files are read.
Even if the example is not about generical Ubuntu with Apache, this kind of solution is given by Amazon for a similar issue with WP here:

https://aws.amazon.com/it/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/wordpress-themes-2mb/

Comment: Tried what you said. I created php.d file because it wasnt there and created zzz.ini file containing upload_max_filesize and post_max_size but there is till no changes in the phpinfo.

Comment: Is there any .htaccess setting php_value post_max_size 8M? ..but I think that if you wrote the application this is not the case.. And did you restart also fpm as apokryfos suggested? The correct command is:
restart php7.0-fpm

Comment: where to locate  .htaccess? I tried restart php7.0-fpm, but it says "command not found".

Comment: @Eliyah, the command depends from your operating system and your php fpm version (it could be also service php7.0-fpm restart or service php7-fpm restart)
You can find an almost exhaustive list here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/189940/how-do-you-restart-php-fpm
The file .htaccess in Apache, to be able to override these values, should be in the "root directory" of your host ( /var/www/project-name/.htaccess or similar)

Comment: I dont have .htaccess in /var/www/html. I confirmed its non-existence throug looking at the putty. I can clearly remember, I havent used it since I log in Amazon Ec2 instance.

Comment: My PHP FPM is inactive so it wont restart.

Comment: I also couldn't find aws.ini